# Reducing redundancy (code duplication) in templates

Tags: theming

The front page of my site needs a very different layout to every other page on the site, so I want to use `page--front.tpl`. However, the front page still has many of the standard regions, and shares the same `main_menu` as the rest of the site.

I have just tried moving the shared "outer" parts of my `page.tpl` (including `main_menu` and `page_bottom`) into the `html.tpl` because I want to use `page--front.tpl` without duplicating code if possible.

Unfortunately, many of these variables, notably `main_menu` are defined only for `page.tpl`, so I've had to hack it into `X_preprocess_html`. This makes me nervous because I don't know what other variables I might be missing: I basically want to refactor it to avoid code duplication.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Or if not, how can I be sure I still have all the variables and regions I need pushed up to `html.tpl`?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can do it in a simple manner, just follow [this](https://drupal.org/node/1056074)

It simply states you can (for example) use
`<?php include 'page.header.inc'; ?>` on a template and include the code for that header.
In this .inc file you just enter the code you want to reuse